# Using LinqToExcel to Create XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-excel

I'm trying to build an XML file from an Excel spreadsheet (no header row). This will be part of a service on a server, so I really don't want to use the MS Office PIO files. I found LinqToExcel on google and tried this code:

```
var clientExcel = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelFileName);
var sourceXml = new XElement("rows",
  clientExcel.WorksheetNoHeader().Select(line => new XElement("row",
      line.Select((column, index) => new XElement("Column_" + index, column)))));
```

The code compiles, but at runtime I get a TargetInvocationException. I've worried at this for the better part of a day, but can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

I'd appreciate it if someone would set me straight.

Answer (score 1):

...if u enable Developer Menu in excel, there's an 'export to xml' option
in 2003 its done very easy by Save As > .XML
in 2007 u might need to prepare mapping schema. but it still better than write codes where u dont know where is your data header

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make clear that these files are data-feeds from several clients, and often are produced by scripts. In any event, we don't have much say over what they send us.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately LinqToExcel can only read data from spreadsheets. It can not add or update spreadsheet data.

Checkout the [ExcelLibary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) project for writing to excel